# Median of time interval in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get the *median time interval* in a group by. My dataset is two columns, column1 is user_ids and column2 is a time interval with the time that user spent on a website. When I group by id and call the MEDIAN function, Redshift throws an error stating that "median(interval)" is not allowed. I left the other columns out of the description since they dont really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Interval is not a Redshift native data type - you cannot have a column of type interval.  However, Redshift does understand interval literals.  Just convert your timestamp differences into seconds (or minutes or hours or days), run MEDIAN(), and then display the result as an interval (if that is what you want).